# Problems with extracting json respnse value in scala using brackets

Tags: regex, scala, gatling

Have tried using " and ' in different combinations to extract the value 13029416243 from the JSON response body I get in a gatling/scala script

```
,\"initialString\":\"13029416243\"},
```

This has been some of my try outs:

```
 .check(regex("initialString(.*?)}").exists.saveAs("initialString"))
```

and

```
 .check(regex("initialString\\\":\\\"(.*?)\\\"}").exists.saveAs("initialString"))
```

where the last one results in this output in the log:

---- Errors --------------------------------------------------------------------

> regex(initialString\":\"(.*?)\"}).find.exists, found nothing

Any help on how to obtain the value?

Comment: Are you sure about your input being `,\"initialString\":\"13029416243\"}` ?

Comment: I suspect the input/json response to be faulty, but a regex should be able to handle this anyways?

Comment: the last regex in my example does not seem to take into account the (.*?) somehow.

Comment: I think you need to take a look at the input. What if there is no "initialString" to begin with?

Comment: There is a response with the actual value initialString. it appears in the log/console in IntelliJ

Comment: In scala you could get the values of the capturing groups like this for example https://ideone.com/p5pR32 or to get a single match only https://ideone.com/tSZwBm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the use of lookbehinds. But to be honest. Json should be parsed with json parsers. Regex is not always a reliable tool for searching in jsons.

```
(?<=initialString\\":\\")\d+\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/Wgeurd/1/

Comment: Assuminyou are extracting a number, like in the example. If there would be alphanumerices, then use \w instead of  \d.

Comment: (?<=initialString\\":\\")\d+\b made this work perfect! Thanks!